# API call before notification display

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

im using "awesome notification for flutter". i achieved to program local notifications at the hour i choose, but also i need to do an api call before notification was displayed to get current weather forecast data.

```
Future<Forecastday> notificationData() async {
 final geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();
 final weatherService = WeatherApiService();

 String actualLocationCoords = await geolocatorService.getCurrentLocation();

 await weatherService.getInfoWeatherLocation(actualLocationCoords);

 return weatherService.forecast![0];
}

Future<void> createWeatherScheduleNotifications(
   NotificationWeekAndTime notificationSchedule) async {
 try {
   final forecast = await notificationData();

   await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
     schedule: NotificationCalendar(
       preciseAlarm: true,
       allowWhileIdle: true,
       // weekday: notificationSchedule.dayOfTheWeek,
       hour: notificationSchedule.timeOfDay.hour,
       minute: notificationSchedule.timeOfDay.minute,
       // repeats: true,
     ),
     content: NotificationContent(
       // payload: ,
       autoDismissible: true,
       wakeUpScreen: true,
       id: Random().nextInt(100),
       channelKey: 'schedule_notification',
       title:
           '${Emojis.wheater_droplet} ${forecast.day.maxtempC} ${forecast.day.mintempC} ${forecast.day.condition.text} ${forecast.day.totalprecipIn} ',
       body: 'Current weather data.',
       // notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
       // bigPicture: 'assets://noti-sun.png',
     ),
     // actionButtons: [
     //   NotificationActionButton(
     //     key: 'MARK_DONE',
     //     label: 'Mark Done',
     //   )
     // ],
   );
 } catch (e) {}
 ;
}
```

i need to triger notificationData(); method.
Does anyone know how to make the call before the notification is displayed?